# What Skype do I need to download?

Tags: software-installation, skype

Skype offers the following downloads:

[image]

Which should I chose? The Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't seem to work - it seems to install then just isn't installed again with no popup error message.

Comment: What do you mean "just isn't installed again"? Where are you seeing it listed as not installed? Does it appear in the applications menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Downloading from [Skype.com](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/), the Ubuntu 12.04 (multiarch) will provide the best software for any elementary Luna or Freya installation. In the future, should a Ubuntu 14.04 version become available, then that would be preferable on Freya.